# MethodInvocation always returns null from pointcut expression

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I defined one pointcut like below:

```
<aop:pointcut id="getAllDataCut" expression=
   "execution(* com.example.test.getAllData(com.example test.User)) and args(usr)" />
```

When i call

```
final Object[] methodArgs= methodInvocation.getArguements();
```

i am getting always null.

Please give some hints.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the arguments sent to the method, you can get them as parameter to your aspect method:

```
public void aspect(JoinPoint joinPoint, com.example.test.User user) {  
  // DO SOME THING WITH user  
}
```

if you want to add aspect for methods with different arguments, you can remove the args from the expression

Comment: Thanks for your answer,is it necessary to define an aspect,samething working with method without arguements.what is the problem with above expression with the arguements.

Comment: the above expression assumes your aspect method taking a user argument like the one I provided, you can use the user argument directly instead  of using methodInvocation.getArguements()

Comment: Hi Mohab,Thanks for you reply,But i want this parameter by calling the method only.because i am constructing variable while runtime based on this argument.

Comment: can you post your aspect method signature?